# What is the aggregation_bits in beacon chain's Attestation?

Tags: blocks, consensus, eth-2.0, validators, beacon-chain

The beacon chains `Attestation` data structure has an `aggregation_bits`

```
class Attestation(Container):
    aggregation_bits: Bitlist[MAX_VALIDATORS_PER_COMMITTEE]
    data: AttestationData
    signature: BLSSignature
```

[See](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#attestation).

I am not sure how to interpret it. I see the size is `MAX_VALIDATORS_PER_COMMITTEE` so my guess is that, it is a list of validators in a particular committee.

From the configurations [here](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#misc-1) it can be seen that `MAX_VALIDATORS_PER_COMMITTEE` has a value of `2 ** 11 = 2,048`

But when I look at the chain explorer, for example [here](https://prater.beaconcha.in/block/2765439#attestations) I see `Aggregation Bits` and `Validators` but not sure how these two relate.

Anyone care enough explain what `aggregation_bits` is? And how it is used in the process of aggregation.

Update:

I found this link [here](https://notes.ethereum.org/@djrtwo/Bkn3zpwxB#Attestation) where it is stated:

> aggregation_bits - a list of bits containing a single bit for each member of the committee. Each validator that participated in this aggregate signature is assigned a value of 1. These bits are ordered by the sort of the associated crosslink committee

Looking at the blockchain explorer again, I am not sure how to map the bits to validator index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I suggest you to look the annotated specs of [Vitalik](https://github.com/ethereum/annotated-spec/blob/master/phase0/beacon-chain.md) and [Ben Edgington](https://benjaminion.xyz/eth2-annotated-spec/phase0/beacon-chain/) when you search for some info on the code. For instance, for the aggregation bit, Ben explains:

> This is the form in which attestations make their way around the network. It is designed to be easily aggregatable: `Attestations` containing identical `AttestationData` can be combined into a single attestation by aggregating the signatures.

And Vitalik says:

> instead of every validator's attestation being included separately, attestations first get broadcasted to an aggregation layer in the network, and then the block proposer can merge all attestations that sign the exact same AttestationData into a single Attestation that gets included on-chain.

Now concerning your updated question, the answer is that you can map aggregation bits with validator's index when you know the committee. In the [instance](https://prater.beaconcha.in/block/2765439#attestations) you've given you can see each attestation has a committee index. Each committee is chosen by a pseudo random algorithm. The function [`get_beacon_committee`](https://benjaminion.xyz/eth2-annotated-spec/phase0/beacon-chain/#get_beacon_committee) returns a list of validator Index. With this list you can map aggregation bits to the validators' index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i still dont get how the list of validator index returned by get_beacon_committee gets mapped to the aggregate bits.

Comment: I mean, the aggregate bits is a list of bits, where 1 representing participating validator...this I understand, but I do not see how to map these 1's to a validator Index which actually identify the validator...Any ideas how this is done?

Comment: It's in the last paragraph, each epoch, committees are shuffled with a pseudo random algorithm. The committee is an ordered list of validator, so once you know the the committee you can map it with a list of 1 and 0 according to the vote they've made. Does this answer your question?